# Caching disables the ability to register to my site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using joomla 3, a catalog website that requires registration in order to get access to several pages.

I'm using RS Form Pro registration plugin. when i turn Joomla's cache on, my users are filling the registration fields and they are also being saved to RS Form Pro submissions list BUT, it doesn't actually register them, no new registered user is being created in the admin and there is no such user when trying to log-in.

Important to say: when caching is disabled, everything works correctly.
how can i make it work without disabling my website's cash?

Comment: When you say caching, which caching are you referring to? The system plugin caching or the one in the Global Configuration? If you're referring to the one in the Global Configuration, which option do you have it set to (Conservative or Progessive)?

Comment: Hey, im using the one in the global configuration and i set it as conservative (also not working with progressive)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the order of the plugins. Make sure that the RS Form system plugin is ordered after the cache plugin.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google found this...

"If you wish to keep Cache enabled on your website, as an alternate solution, you can create a RSForm! Pro menu item (Menus > Add new menu item > Select - RSForm! Pro - Form > Choose the form and publish"

http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/474-my-forms-are-not-working-correctly-with-cache-enabled.html

If that doesn't work, then asking on their forum may be better than here as the people who actually coded it should be around to help.